# VS 2010 Beta 2 - unable to update service reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, service-reference

I'm  upgrading a project from VS2008 to VS2010B2
For some reason, after the project was upgraded, the code generated by the reference is missing, and I cannot re-create the code by reconfiguring the service reference, because I'm getting the following error:

> The configuration for the service
>   reference could not be updated due to
>   the following issue: An error occurred
>   creating the configuration section
>   handler for
>   system.serviceModel/behaviors:
>   Extension element 'webHttp' cannot be
>   added to this element.  Verify that
>   the extension is registered in the
>   extension collection at
>   system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.

The machine has the configuration for webHttp:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
   <behaviorExtensions>
    ...
    <add name="webHttp" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.WebHttpElement, System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    ...
                    </behaviorExtensions>
   ...
```

Comment: are you upgrading to 4.0 or stay with 3.5? service model changed in 4.0.

Comment: Try reproducing the problem with the released version of VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Right-click on the solution, Clean;
2. Right-click the web reference, Update Web reference;
3. Right-click on the solution, Rebuild.